# smoothstate.js reverse animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

having some trouble with the reverse animation of scene-elements within the smoothstate.js libary.
i am working on the site: [LINK](http://niecore.de/herzstuecke)

actually the ".is-exiting" class applies to DOM but the animation is not happening
here is my css:

```
.animated .scene_element{
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
          animation-fill-mode: both;

}

.animated.is-exiting .scene_element {
            -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
            animation-direction: alternate-reverse; 
 }
```

and the jquery

```
;(function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var $body    = $('html, body'), // Define jQuery collection 
      content  = $('#wrapper').smoothState({
        onStart : {
          duration: 500,
          render: function () {
            content.toggleAnimationClass('is-exiting');

            // Scroll user to the top
            $body.animate({ 'scrollTop': 0 });

          }
        }
      }).data('smoothState');
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what exactly is the expected, desired outcome?

Comment: @isim it's clear he want the is-exiting animation works, which is not at the moment.

Comment: @niecore, please do share your html so I can see it, I do have the same problem as well, I heard toggleAnimationClass is already deprecated. I'm still figuring it oout

Answer (score 1):

Your animation duration declared in css is longer than the overall animation declared in javascript.

1s vs 0.5s

```css
.animated .scene_element{
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-duration: 1s;
```

```js
onStart : {
          duration: 500,
          render: function () {
```